# WTForms SelectMultipleField: disable validation

Tags: validation, python-3.x, wtforms

I have a  SelectMultipleField that is populated/modified at runtime using JavaScript. My problem is that this violates the validator, hence the call to `form.validate_on_submit()` always fails.

```
SelectMultipleField('Test', coerce=int)
```

I already tried to set my custom validator that does nothing:

```
def dummy_validator(form, field):
    print("check: "+str(field.data))

SelectMultipleField('Test', coerce=int, [dummy_validator])
```

However this still fails. For example I get the error message `'7' is not a valid choice for this field`.

What is needed to make SelectMultipleField pass the validation process started by `form.validate_on_submit()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the `pre_validation` which is always executed before any specified validators are executed. Therefore the `dummy_validator` in my question will not change this behavior.

The only way to change this is to implements an own field that derives from `SelectMultipleField`:

```
class NoValidationSelectMultipleField(SelectMultipleField):
    def pre_validate(self, form):
        """per_validation is disabled"""
```

Afterwards one can directly use the field in a form:

```
NoValidationSelectMultipleField('Test', coerce=int)
```

Comment: This worked for me in a very similar problem, where I was dynamically creating options in a hidden field with jquery and the form was complaining with the same error. Does this mean I need to write custom validation after form.validate_on_submit?

Comment: So is this a bug in wtforms?  (I had to resort to this technique as well)....